# Can't debug MS Access 2013 Run-time Error 91

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I can't seem to de-bug the following run-time error 91.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs3 As DAO.Recordset

Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Company, " & _
"StDev(DayLog) As [StDevDayLog], " & _
"Count(Date) As [CountDay] " & _
"FROM Table1 " & _
"WHERE (Date <= #6/1/2013# " & _
"And Date > #6/1/2008#) " & _
"GROUP BY Company;")
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: You have to create a DB object before you can open a recordset.

Comment: What is the error message text you get with error 91?

Comment: Wow, I feel pretty stupid right now. can't believe I missed that! thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the object variable to `CurrentDb` before attempting `db.OpenRecordset`

```vb
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset ...
```

It seems your table includes a field named *Date*, which is also the name of a function.  You can bracket that name or qualify it with the table name or alias to avoid confusing the db engine.